How to enable zooming + scrolling for Flutter web apps only on mobile browsers?
I have built and published a Flutter web app and tested it on both desktop & mobile browsers. Since the design of the app appears smaller when accessed on a mobile browser due to the small screen size, I am trying to enable zooming using the 2 fingers pinching gesture like all other popular websites.
I tried using many plugins including:(All support Web and mobile platforms)

https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_zoom_release_unzoom
https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_scrollable
https://pub.dev/packages/custom_zoom_widget
https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_to_zoom_scrollable

But, the problem is that the zooming works fine when I run on mobile devices as an application, but when I run on the desktop browser it misbehaves. The mouse scrolls now
does the zooming and I cannot scroll down the pages anymore.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinch_to_zoom_scrollable/pinch_to_zoom_scrollable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child:kIsWeb?content():PinchToZoomScrollableWidget(child: content())
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget content(){
    return Column(
        children: [
          Container(color:)
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
         Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          )
        ],
    );
  }

How can I just add the zooming feature when viewing on a mobile browser and not mess up the other platforms? Why doesn't Flutter support this normal behavior by default?

2024 stable Solution
Tested on:

Flutter 3.24.1
Dart 3.5.1

Starting Flutter versions > 3.24 the solution using the div and hostElement mentioned below no longer works. You can zoom areas of the HTML page where the Flutter App is not present, otherwise, you cannot pinch to zoom on your phone browser.
The updated sample app using the Multiview technique suggested by the Flutter team to look at in their documentation also does not solve the problem of zooming in mobile browsers.
I found this simple solution to solve the problem using a combination of 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' and InteractiveViewer widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  GetMaterialApp createGetMaterialAppRouter(){
    return GetMaterialApp.router(
      routeInformationProvider: AppRouter.goRouter.routeInformationProvider,
      routerDelegate: AppRouter.goRouter.routerDelegate,
      routeInformationParser: AppRouter.goRouter.routeInformationParser,
      backButtonDispatcher: AppRouter.goRouter.backButtonDispatcher,
      builder: (context, child) => ResponsiveBreakpoints.builder(
        child: child!,
        breakpoints: [
          const Breakpoint(start: 0, end: 450, name: MOBILE),
          const Breakpoint(start: 451, end: 800, name: TABLET),
          const Breakpoint(start: 801, end: 1920, name: DESKTOP),
          const Breakpoint(start: 1921, end: double.infinity, name: '4K'),
        ],
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final isWebMobile = kIsWeb && (defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.iOS || defaultTargetPlatform == TargetPlatform.android);

    if(isWebMobile)
    return InteractiveViewer(
      child: createGetMaterialAppRouter()
    );
    else
     return createGetMaterialAppRouter();
  }
}

2024 stable Solution (Using embedding) [Works up till Flutter 3.22]
First, make sure to update your Flutter and Dart SDK versions.
At the time of writing this solution, they were:

Flutter 3.19.6
Dart  3.3.4

Then, you will be able to use Flutter's new feature which enables you to embed a Flutter app into an HTML page. This will enable you to encapsulate your Flutter app in a normal HTML web page, plus allow you to add custom JS and CSS files from other web projects.
Source
Thus, you will have the normal pinch-to-zoom effect on mobile phones + the swipe-to-refresh action.
Flutter sample project
BUG:
I have written below the minimal code you need, plus a FIX that allows you to make the Flutter app. fill the whole screen on the browser of mobile devices.
Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/" />

  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" />
  <meta name="description" content="A Flutter Web Element embedding demo." />

<!-- This line fixed the problem when trying to make the app fill 
out the whole screen size
on mobile browsers, as done in the CSS file below -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="Flutter Element embedding" />
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png" />
  <link rel="preload" as="image" href="icons/Icon-maskable-512.png" />


  <title>Element embedding</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" />

  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>

<div id="flutter_app"></div>

<script>
      window.addEventListener("load", function (ev) {
        // Embed flutter into div#flutter_target
        let target = document.querySelector("#flutter_app");
        _flutter.loader.loadEntrypoint({
          onEntrypointLoaded: async function (engineInitializer) {
            let appRunner = await engineInitializer.initializeEngine({
              hostElement: target,
            });
            await appRunner.runApp();
          },
        });
      });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

style.css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background-color: #fff;
  background-image: radial-gradient(
      ellipse at bottom,
      #fafafa 5%,
      transparent 60%
    ),
    linear-gradient(136deg, transparent, #eee 290%),
    linear-gradient(115deg, #fafafa, transparent 40%),
    linear-gradient(180deg, transparent 0, #ddd 70%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at -70% -180%, transparent 80%, #eee 0),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at bottom, #71c7ee 40%, transparent 80%),
    radial-gradient(ellipse at 5% 340%, transparent 80%, #ddd 0);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #555;
}

/** The style for the DIV where flutter will be rendered, and the CSS fx */
#flutter_app {
  border: 0px solid #aaa;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 150ms ease-in;
  align-self: center;
}

That's it!


Old Hack (Not recommended, as it fails upon navigation)
I was able to find a workaround solution using a combination of 2 plugins:

https://pub.dev/packages/platform_detector
https://pub.dev/packages/pinch_to_zoom_scrollable

This way, I only activate the zooming feature when the web app is accessed in a mobile browser.
N.B: The below code quality and structure is only for demonstration purposes, and should not be used in real app. development.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:pinch_to_zoom_scrollable/pinch_to_zoom_scrollable.dart';
import 'package:platform_detector/platform_detector.dart';

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int myFlag = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    if (isAndroidOs() || isIOS()) {
      myFlag = 1;
    } else {
      if (isAndroidApp()) {
        myFlag = 2;
      } else {
        if (isWindowsWeb() || isLinuxWeb() || isMacOsWeb()) {
          myFlag = 4;
        }
      }
    }
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return myFlag == 0
        ? PinchToZoomScrollableWidget(
            child: content(),
            resetDuration: Duration(minutes: 5),
          )
        : content();
  }

  Widget content() {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          Container(color: Colors.green,width: 100,height: 100,),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          )
        ],
      )),
    );
  }

